# For which RSA moduli, precisely, is $e=d$ for all $e$?

Tags: rsa, public-key, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residuosity

[This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/rsa-if-n-35-show-that-e-will-equal-d) shows that there are at least two valid RSA moduli $n$, namely $35$ and $91$, such that for **any** $e$ coprime to $\lambda(n)$, $$e^2\equiv1\mod\lambda(n)\text.$$
Reading the linked question, I wondered if there is a "simple" description of the set of numbers $n$ that have this property. In particular, are there infinitely many such numbers?

Comment: Do you really want $\pmod{\varphi(n)}$ or rather $\pmod{\lambda(n)}$?

Comment: I *actually* want $\lambda(n)$, you're right. (The confusion arises from the fact that for products of distinct primes, these are equal.)

Comment: "for products of distinct primes, these are equal" I don't think so. For odd primes (p-1) and (q-1) always share the factor two, so $\lambda$ is strictly smaller than $\varphi$.

Answer (score 6):

> I wondered if there is a "simple" description of the set of numbers n that have this property.

Yes, there is; $n$ has a prime factorization $p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot ... \cdot p_n$ such that all the primes are unique (i.e. $n$ is square-free), and for each prime factor $p_i$, $p_i-1$ must be a divisor of 24.  In other words, each prime must be a member of the set $\{2, 3, 5, 7, 13\}$

Why is this?  Well, $e^2 \equiv 1 \mod \lambda(n)$ (for $e$ r.p. to $\lambda(n)$) is equivalent to $e^2 \equiv 1 \mod p_i-1 $ for all $i$ (for $e$ r.p. to $p_i-1$); this latter holds only if $p_i-1$ is a divisor of 24.

As a consequence, we see that there is only a finite number of such modulii; if we restrict ourselves to modulii with two factors, we see that 91 is the largest possible.  If we include multiprimes, then the largest possible is $2730 = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 13$

Comment: are you sure about the "square-free" thing ? $n = 45 = 3^2 5 \Rightarrow \lambda(n) = 12$; now $12 | 24$ thus $e^2 = 1 \bmod \lambda(45) \forall e $ coprime with $\lambda(45)$ and $n$ is part of this set, right ?

Comment: @CédricVanRompay: for $n=45$, there are ciphertexts that cannot be uniquely decrypted (e.g. $c=36$), for any $e>1$, hence I would claim that is not a valid RSA modulus.